# h2o autoencoders high error (h2o.mse)

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to use h2o to create an autoencoder using its deeplearning function. I am feeding a set of data about 4000x50 in size to the deeplearning function (hidden node c(200)) and then using h2o.mse to check its error and I am getting about 0.4, a fairly high value.

Is there anyway to reduce that error by changing something in the deeplearning function?

Answer (score 0):

I assume everything is the defaults, except defining a single hidden layer with 200 nodes?

Your first set of things to try are:

- Use more epochs (or use less aggressive early stopping criteria)
- Use a 2nd hidden layer
- Use more nodes in your hidden layer(s)
- Get more training data

Note that *all* of those will increase your training time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use H2OGridSearch to find the best autoencoder model with the smallest MSE. 
Below is an example in Python. [Here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html#grid-search-example-in-r) you can find example in R.

```
def tuneAndTrain(hyperParameters, model, trainDataFrame):
    h2o.init()
    trainData=trainDataFrame.values        
    trainDataHex=h2o.H2OFrame(trainData)
    modelGrid = H2OGridSearch(model,hyper_params=hyperParameters)
    modelGrid.train(x=list(range(0,int(len(trainDataFrame.columns)))),training_frame=trainDataHex)
    gridperf1 = modelGrid.get_grid(sort_by='mse', decreasing=True)
    bestModel = gridperf1.models[0]
    return bestModel
```

And you can call the above function to find and train the best model:

```
hiddenOpt = [[50,50],[100,100], [5,5,5],[50,50,50]]
l2Opt = [1e-4,1e-2]
hyperParameters = {"hidden":hiddenOpt, "l2":l2Opt}
bestModel=tuneAndTrain(hyperParameters,H2OAutoEncoderEstimator(activation="Tanh", ignore_const_cols=False, epochs=200),dataFrameTrainPreprocessed)
```